# ORA-28860: Fatal SSL error, can't create REST Data Source or send Emails

Tags: oracle, apex

I have installed Oracle databese 18c XE, and Oracle APEX 21.2.0,
I was getting the below error when trying to (Create REST Data Source) for APEX Application

"ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list(ACL)"

after doing some research I connected sys as sysdba using SQL Plus, and then executed the below:

[ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = XEDBA1;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrPV5.png)

after that I executed the below commands:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
        host => '*',
        ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect', 'resolve'),
                           principal_name => 'APEX_210200',
                           principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/

BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
        host => '*',
        ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect', 'resolve'),
                           principal_name => 'MDS_SCHEMA',
                           principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```

[ACL Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqjsx.png)

where:
APEX_210200 is the INTERNAL workspace schema
MDS_SCHEMA is the schema for the workspace which the application was build

Now I'm getting the error "ORA-28860: Fatal SSL error" when trying to create REST Data Source

[Create REST Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cB6S.png)
[ORA-28860](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSIVt.png)

And I can't send emails knowing that SMTP server is set correctly

Please help so I can Create REST Data Source and send Emails through my APEX application